# What does the Windows kernel consist of?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, kernel

Is it just a single file, like win.com?

Comment: You might be interested in the Windows Internals book: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very very roughly speaking,

Windows 95, 98, Me;
**kernel32.dll**

Windows NT+
**ntoskrnl.exe** (Edit: Corrected, ty)

In reality it's a large collection of libraries and executable files. 
It is the most fundamental part of the OS, handling memory, cpu and other hardware I/O. It include components such as the *Windows Driver Model*, the *Kernel Transaction Manager*, and the *Graphics Device Interface* (win32k.sys) all of which are large components themselves.

(Win.com was used to run windows from DOS)

Comment: ntdll.dll is a user mode thing, ntoskrnl.exe (or one of its variants) contains the components that you mentioned in kernel mode. I agree with the comment of getting the Windows Internals book though, that has a full discussion of everything involved here.

Comment: Is it not the case that ntdll.dll contains some kernel-mode functions? Including I/O & threading? That said, I see you registered just to correct me, so you're probably right! Thanks for the correction =).

Comment: I actually just registered because I had never heard of this site before :) ntdll.dll is mostly just the user mode stub for the system services which are implemented in kernel mode. This is described indirectly here: http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?id=257